# How to load video with opencv-python on Windows machine? (Difference btw Windows / Linux ?)

Tags: python, linux, opencv, video, windows-10

I am new to the opencv(3.0.0)-python(2.7).
There is an error with loading the video on a windows machine with cv2.Videocapture. I actually tried to use haar classifier using the video, but since the video file wasn't playing I tried the following simple code.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('‪C:\\Users\\jimmy\\Desktop\\bbd.mp4')

if cap.isOpened():
    print 'Yes'

else:
    print 'No'
```

And it keeps returning 'No'.
I don't think it's the problem of directory because it worked perfectly with images and imshow, imread functions. So, these kinds of errors always happen when I try to load a video.

I actually used raspberrypi to load a video before and it worked perfectly, so I am wondering is there any difference between rpi and windows machine that I don't know. Also please tell me how to fix it.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: what happens when you print the value of `cap.isOpened()`

Comment: the path of video seems to be very weird to  me. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: I guess the parth of the video is correct. I have tried with the image in the same directory with imshow, imread and it worked perfectly

Comment: Regarding cap.isOpened() it returns False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your path from this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('‪C:\\Users\\jimmy\\Desktop\\bbd.mp4')
```

to this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('‪C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/bbd.mp4')
```

OpenCV doesn't like the forward slashes for some reason